# React-native getting 'require cycle' in a loop when fetching

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native and I'm currently trying to create a map with levels and exercises. Right now, I just want to get, for each level, the maximum exercise value to create as many buttons as there are exercise by level. But I'm having this warning displayed: "Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle."

It's displayed a lot of time and I don't have my JSON.

Here is the code I have for the moment:

```
  export async function getExercisesByLevel() {
  console.log("getExercicesByLevel");
  const url = 'http://XXX/Appli/appli-api.php?niveauExerciceCount'

  try {
    let req = await fetch(url)
    let response = await req.json()
    return response
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Here is the code I'm using to retrieve the JSON.
Then I'm just calling the function:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native'
import { getLevels, getExercisesByLevel } from '../API/NiveauxAPI'

    class Niveaux extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { niveaux: "" }
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        {this._displayLevelsMap()}
      }

      _displayLevelsMap() {
        getExercisesByLevel().then(niveaux => {
          this.setState({
            niveaux: niveaux
          })
        })
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
          </View>
        )
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      view: {
        flex: 1,
      }
    })

    export default Niveaux
```

All of this is contained in a StackNavigator:

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import Niveaux from '../Components/Niveaux'

const SearchStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Search: {
    screen: Niveaux,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Niveaux"
    }
  }
})

const App = createAppContainer(SearchStackNavigator)
export default App
```

Please let me know what I'm not doing correctly (there might be a lot of things :p).

In advance, thanks!